# Não consigo centralizar uma imagem semanticamente

Tags: html5, css3

Como deixar uma imagem no centro da tela tentei colocar um `text-align:center` e não funcionou.

Segue o meu código html:

```html
<header>
      <img src="images/bg-header.png" id="bg-header">
        <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cases</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Orçamento</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>            
        </ul>

      <img src="images/web-sky-logo.png" id="logo-header">
</header>
```

Obs.: A imagem que preciso renomear e a que esta com o `id="logo-header"` e ela tem que ficar centralizada no Google Chrome, Safari e Mozila.

Comment: Fica como dica também usar: 

header img#logo-header{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;  
}

Comment: entao amigo e assim a resposta que marquei como correta funcionou ate entao pesquisei as tags com o link que foi passado para min pois eu antes usava a tag center e ela foi trocada por tex-algin center e foi me dada a resposta com essa tag bom funcionou eu nao manjo muito de html e vou pedindo ajuda e oque for funcionando marco como resposta porem se achou que esta errado gostaria de ver sua resposta  assim pra min esta certo e é como te sisse nao manjo muito de html css porem se acha que esta incorreto gostaria que me mostra-se a forma certa =3

Comment: a resposta do Jefferson não está errado não, muito menos a do Jeremias. A questão é que a sugestão do Jefferson acaba que adicionando mais conteúdo HTML, sendo que é possível centralizar a imagem apenas com CSS (Tanto que a resposta do Jeremias recebeu mais votos!). Mas nenhuma resposta está erra não! Inclusive a minha sugestão também funciona!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
<header>
      <p class="text-center"><img src="images/bg-header.png" id="bg-header"></p>
        <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cases</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Orçamento</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>            
        </ul>

      <p class="text-center"><img src="images/web-sky-logo.png" id="logo-header"></p>
</header>
```

CSS:

```css
.text-center{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: amigo aproveitando seu post e uma boa pratica usar a tag <center>????

Comment: Pois é, a tag center foi depreciada no HTML. http://www.devmedia.com.br/tags-e-atributos-depreciados-na-html/28042

Comment: hmmm entendi mais então não e muito bom ultilizar ela neh

Comment: "A tag <center> por exemplo é corriqueiramente chamada de “tag do preguiçoso”, pois é bastante usada para centralizar elementos quando os mesmos deveriam ter tal efeito aplicado através de um estilo CSS. De tal forma, a partir da nova especificação o seu efeito fica abolido, inclusive o de usá-la em conjunto com uma tabela (<table>) para alinhar a mesma e seus respectivos elementos internos.

Leia mais em: Tags e atributos depreciados na HTML http://www.devmedia.com.br/tags-e-atributos-depreciados-na-html/28042#ixzz3abhrT13d"

Comment: Hoje em dia não hehe

Comment: Olá @Kirito, se você NÃO estiver usando HTML5 não tem problema algum utiliza-la. Porém não é recomendável utilizar código em depreciação, ou seja, no HTML5 já não existe essa tag. Para consultar se uma tag está em uso ou não, pesquise no google a palavra `tag` + `nomedatag` por exemplo `tag center` o primeiro resultato geralmente é uma [página do W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp) que trás na sessão **Definition and Usage** a informação se ela está ou não depreciada.

Comment: Isso aí.. certissimo @KaduAmaral

Comment: sim sim obrigado pela ajuda deu certim o seu codigo rsrs =3 daqui 2 min eu marcomo como resposta

Answer (score 6):

Crie a seguinte regra css:

```
header img{
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }
```